# What parameters do I pass to 'filter' function in Scala

Tags: python, scala

I am having trouble understanding this Scala code involving a lambda expression:

```
object ScalaList {
  case class Student(rollNo : Int, name : String, marks : Int)
  val students=   List(Student(1,"A",10),Student(2,"B",14))
  var toppers = students.filter(s=>s.marks>10)    //> toppers  : List[ScalaList.Student] = List(Student(2,B,14))
}
```

It works, but the filter function takes an argument 's' that I didn't define. What is 's'. Also, if this were pandas, I think I would need to supply an axis=1 parameter. Why don't I need it in Scala

Comment: Because this is just a list not a dataframe, and this is Scala not python. `filter` takes a **function** so `s => s.mark > 5` is defining `s` right there. Is like when you define a method like `def plusOne(x: Int): Int = x + 1` where was x defined? Right there, otherwise wouldn't be any point in being able to define functions or methods. `s` will take the value of each **Student** in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it would help to compare Python implementation

```
>>> from pydantic import BaseModel
>>>
>>> class Student(BaseModel):
...     rollNo: int
...     name: str
...     marks: int
...
>>> students = [
...     Student(rollNo=1, name="A", marks=10),
...     Student(rollNo=2, name="B", marks=14)
... ]
>>>
>>> list(filter(lambda s: s.marks > 10, students))
[Student(rollNo=2, name='B', marks=14)]
```

with similar Scala implementation

```
scala> case class Student(
     |     rollNo: Int,
     |     name: String,
     |     marks: Int
     | )
     | val students = List(
     |     Student(1, "A", 10),
     |     Student(2, "B", 14)
     | )
     | students.filter(s => s.marks > 10)
class Student
val students: List[Student] = List(Student(1,A,10), Student(2,B,14))
val res0: List[Student] = List(Student(2,B,14))
```

where we see Scala lambda

```
s => s.marks > 10
```

is similar to Python lambda

```
lambda s: s.marks > 10
```

which should make it clear that declared lambda parameter `s` becomes a local variable inside the body of the lambda.

Consider Scala API documentation for [List#filter](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#filter(p:A=%3EBoolean):List%5BA%5D) as well as [Scala for Python Developers](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/scala-for-python-devs.html#filtering) section of Scala 3 Book.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the argument to the `filter` method is not `s`, but rather the entirety of `s => s.marks > 10`: this is the syntax to define an *anonymous* function that takes some `s` and returns the result of the comparison of its `marks` field with the literal `10`. In this context, `s` is just the made up name of a parameter of the function, just like it would be if it was defined as a method as in the following example:

```
def marksGreaterThan10(s: Student): Boolean = s.marks > 10
```

One thing that could make someone a bit confused about the syntax is that the compiler itself is able to infer the types based on your input, making it very compact and readable, but perhaps a bit opaque for newcomers. Note that without the appropriate context (i.e. a list of `Student`s is being filtered, therefore the input type of the function *must* be a `Student`), the compiler would complain about the `missing parameter type` and you would need to provide one, as in the following example (where I assign the *anonymous function* to a variable, so that I can use it in some other part of the program):

```
val marksGreaterThan10 = (s: Student) => s.marks > 10
```

Note that both a method and a function can be passed to a *higher-order function* (a function that can take a function as a parameter or return one as an output) like `filter`.

```
final case class Student(marks: Int)

val marksGreaterThan10Function = (s: Student) => s.marks > 10

def marksGreaterThan10Method(s: Student): Boolean = s.marks > 10

val students = Seq(Student(1), Student(11))

// Both of these returns `Seq(Student(11))`
students.filter(marksGreaterThan10Function)
students.filter(marksGreaterThan10Method)
```

You can play around with the code above [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/A6pulKxxRnqsp6Htu7zLpw) on Scastie.

If you are familiar with the Java *lambda expression* syntax, `->` is more or less equivalent to `=>` and you would have written something like:

```
students.stream().filter(s -> s.marks > 10)
```